# can the first compound list in POSIX shell case construct have alternatives among patterns?

Tags: shell

The POSIX shell standard

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html

says

```
The format for the case construct is as follows:

case word in
    [(]pattern1) compound-list;;
    [[(]pattern[ | pattern] ... ) compound-list;;] ...
    [[(]pattern[ | pattern] ... ) compound-list]
esac
```

which seems to indicate the first compound list pattern is special - there can be only one, no alternatives denoted by `|` as for the other ones (and reading the POSIX standards elsewhere, `pattern` itself does not support alternatives).

I tried, using latest `dash`, and seems to work:

```
$case foobar in
    ( foo* | *bar ) echo OK
esac
$OK
```

There is no mention of "behavior is unspecified".  So if the shell did not support that, it should emit an error message.

It cannot be a typo in the standard - too many characters involved.

So clearly I am not understanding something.  Does POSIX shell support alternatives among patterns for the first compound list of a case construct, and how is it documented?

Comment: This behavior predates POSIX -- even 1970s Bourne allows alternations in that position. (Not that POSIX sh is a strict superset -- it's not -- but referring back is a pretty good clue about intent).

Comment: I am sorry - I tried to find another question about this and failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The canonical grammar is given in the standard:

```
case_clause      : Case WORD linebreak in linebreak case_list    Esac
                 | Case WORD linebreak in linebreak case_list_ns Esac
                 | Case WORD linebreak in linebreak              Esac
                 ;
case_list_ns     : case_list case_item_ns
                 |           case_item_ns
                 ;
case_list        : case_list case_item
                 |           case_item
                 ;
case_item_ns     :     pattern ')'               linebreak
                 |     pattern ')' compound_list linebreak
                 | '(' pattern ')'               linebreak
                 | '(' pattern ')' compound_list linebreak
                 ;
case_item        :     pattern ')' linebreak     DSEMI linebreak
                 |     pattern ')' compound_list DSEMI linebreak
                 | '(' pattern ')' linebreak     DSEMI linebreak
                 | '(' pattern ')' compound_list DSEMI linebreak
                 ;
pattern          :             WORD         /* Apply rule 4 */
                 | pattern '|' WORD         /* Do not apply rule 4 */
```

Note that `pattern`, which allows `|`s, is used in every position.

Comment: oh I see, there are two places in the standard where this is specified, in a contradictory manner.  However, the grammar section explicitly states that it takes precedence over the preceding section.    Thank you!